# absolute positioned div images overlapping

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, absolute

I am trying to put together a social-media bar for a website and am using images as the links to each. I have an animation set for each image and for the animation to work properly, the `img` position needs to be set to `absolute`. The problem I am running into with this however is all the images stack on top of each other within the `div="crossfade`. I have been working on this for 3 hours now and have no logical solution. How can I separate the individual links.

HTML:

```
<div id="social-icons">
    <div id="crossfade">
         <a href="http://www.facebook.com/lostbydesignband" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/facebookLogoHover.png" width="55" height="55" class="bottom" >
                    <img src="images/facebookLogo.png" width="55" height="55" class="top" >
         </a>
         <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="images/gmailLogoHover.png" width="55" height="55" class="bottom" >
                    <img src="images/gmailLogo.png" width="55" height="55" class="top" >
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#social-icons {
    background-color:#291F32;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0px;
}

#crossfade {
    position:relative;
}

#crossfade img {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

#crossfade img:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just style the images like style="left:55px"?

Comment: the `left` and `right` is what's centering the links, otherwise they float towards the right and still on top of each other

Comment: can you float your anchor tags and give them a width? hard to understand whats happening without a fiddle

Comment: floating the anchors doesn't help either. really stuck with this, and I imagine it's a pretty simple fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not styling the anchors that contain the images. As the images have a `position:absolute`, they'll be outside of the page flow, their containing anchors will have a width and height of 0, and the images will overlap.

You can easily fix this issue by styling the anchors:

- Adding a `position:relative` so the images are relative to the `a` and not the `#crossfade` (add a `text-align:center` on the parent to make them still display centered)
- Setting a `height` and a `width` (to 55px that is the same as the pics)
- Setting the display as `inline-bock` so the changes in `height` and `width` are recognized.

The result would be like this (I updated the pics to random ones so you can see the effect):

```css
#social-icons {
    background-color:#291F32;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    margin:0px;
}

/* modified CSS */
#crossfade {
    text-align:center;
}

#crossfade a {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:55px;
    height:55px;
}
/* end modified CSS */

#crossfade img {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

#crossfade img:hover {
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="social-icons">
    <div id="crossfade">
         <a href="http://www.facebook.com/lostbydesignband" target="_blank">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/55/55/abstract/" width="55" height="55" class="bottom" >
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/55/55/animals/" width="55" height="55" class="top" >
         </a>
         <a href="#" target="_blank">
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/55/55/people/" width="55" height="55" class="bottom" >
             <img src="http://lorempixel.com/55/55/sports/" width="55" height="55" class="top" >
         </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also see it on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4f6o2ny/

Comment: just pasted all the css from your example in now instead of just the edited, and I have the same overlapping problem as before

Comment: Could you share a JSFiddle with a demo so I can see it? There may be a conflict in the CSS rules

Comment: The CSS for `#crossfade img` in your codepen does not match the one in this question. You have a different rule: `left:55px`. Add my code, remove that rule from  `#crossfade img` (or set it up as `left:0`), and the solution will work fine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwaMVw

Comment: ok, it works now, didn't cut and paste it in right i guess. much apprecitated